# jdbc DriverManager.getConnection("connection_url", "username", "password");

Tags: java, jdbc

Can anyone tell me wats happening here

```
Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("connection_url", "username", "password");
```

How connection interface and driverManager class are related ? 
I mean con is a connection interface reference which can point to an object of a class which implements connection interface or an object/instance which is related to connection interface .....what "DriverManager.getConnection" is returning and how it can be referred by a connection reference ??

I know the basic answer dat it returns a connection by checking the url of the driver but what is actually happening in detail ?

I am a beginner java student please help

Answer (score 2):

The `DriverManager` keeps track of all JDBC `Driver`s that have been loaded in your JVM (there are a couple of ways in which a `Driver` can be loaded).

When you ask the `DriverManager` to open a connection for you, it asks each of the loaded drivers whether it can handle the URL that you've specified.
If the `Driver` can handle the URL, then it is asked to connect to the database using the supplied username and password. The `Driver` supplies a connection object that implements the `Connection` interface.

The `DriverManager` really is just a small class that knows about each loaded `Driver` and handles picking the right one. The implementation of `Connection` (and `Statement`, etc) is all handled by the `Driver`.

Answer (score 1):

> I mean con is a connection interface reference which can't point to an object of a class which implements connection interface

Wrong. It *can* and it *must*. The actual implementation class is provided by the JDBC driver vendor.

Answer (score 0):

See, here `DriverManager.getConnection("connection_url", "username", "password");` is not the obj of `java.sql.Connection(interface)`. It's the obj of JDBC driver Class that implements Connection (I). please note that Interface can't be instantiated (i. object can't be created) but it can hold / refer to obj of implementation class (i.e Driver class and driver class changes based on database we want connect to).